# Enterprise Architect - MDA converst Map to List

Tags: java, enterprise-architect, mda

I am using EA for creation of PIM. When I generate java code directly I am getting correct data type where I want - Map where I set qualifiers on association properties which as I understand meas that it is going to be a map. And that works as expected. Hovewer when I do the MDA transformation and generete code - properties are conveted to List (which is bad) bug setters and getters method keep using Map as in the following example:

```
public class Check {

private List< Comp> comps;
private List< Gratuity> gratuities;

public Check(){

}

public Map<String, Comp> getcomps(){
    return comps;
}

public Map<String, Gratuity> getgratuities(){
    return gratuities;
}
```

I am using default transformation package for Java. I tried to add following line to Java transformation for connector is source section

```
%connectorType%
%PI="\n  "%
{
%TRANSFORM_CURRENT()%
%TRANSFORM_REFERENCE("Connector",connectorGUID)%
Source
{
%TRANSFORM_REFERENCE("Class",connectorSourceElemGUID)%
access=%qt%%connectorSourceAccess == "Public" ? "Private" : value%%qt%
qualifier=%connectorSourceQualifier%
%TRANSFORM_CURRENT("Source","access")% 
}
Target
{
%TRANSFORM_REFERENCE("Class",connectorDestElemGUID)%
access=%qt%%connectorDestAccess == "Public" ? "Private" : value%%qt%
%TRANSFORM_CURRENT("Target","access")%
%PI="\n"%
}
}
```

but that doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete answer, but it's too long to go in a comment.

I'm not convinced that the connector source qualifier determines which collection class (Map, List) is used. There are three things involved here: the MDA transform template, the code generation template and the collection class options.

Check Tools -- Options -- Source Code Engineering -- Java. There you'll find settings for Default Collection Class and Additional Collection Classes (these are used for attributes), and (by clicking the Collection Classes button) collection class settings for associations. Check these.

Also, check the Linked Attribute Declaration template for Java code generation. It seems to me that this does not check the qualifier, but it does check %linkAttCollectionClass%.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply form Enterprise Architect support which says it is bug - original message:

I am sorry it does not work because there's an issue with regard to transformation of the Connector 'qualifier'.

The transformation template '%TRANSFORM_CURRENT()%' (and your new added 'qualifier="tr: String') is all correct, but the issue makes it fail to transform that qualifier value across.

We are going to resolve this issue in a future release of EA. Unfortunately I cannot provide a timeframe for release.

Issue ID: 13106266